# Replace dot & comma with blank in logstash filter

Tags: logstash-configuration

I want to replace every dot and comma with a blank in logstash but its not working.

The code below is not giving any errors, but it does not replace the dots and commas:

```
gsub => ["new_padd", "[.,]", "", 
        "new_ladd", "[.,]", ""]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression code is like below:

```
let str="This is simple, text.";
 var x= str.replace(/[.,]/g, '');
```

**output**: This is simple text